# What did "18/9", "25/", and "30/" mean in this 1800 British document?

Tags: economic-history

In "The Petition of the Master Taylors of London and its Vicinity, December 1800" (reproduced in Galton, [1896](https://archive.org/details/selectdocumentsi00galtiala/page/86/mode/2up)), it is stated

> the wages and allowances ... were accordingly settled at the rate of 18/9 per week ...
>
> the wages the journeymen now receive is 25/ per week ...
>
> have refused to work unless their respective masters will raise the wages they now receive to 30/ per week

I'm guessing that "18/9" means 18s9d, while "25/" and "30/" mean 25s and 30s?

Comment: I came here though the HNQ, but I expected to end up on history.SE rather than Economics, tbh.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes your guess is correct.

In fact, the forward slash punctuation mark "/" actually comes to us through its being the abbreviation for the English shilling.

From Humez and Humez ([2008](https://books.google.com/books?id=dnLnBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&dq=%22also+variously+known+as+a+solidus,+virgule,+or+just+plain+slash%22&redir_esc=y)):

> ... forward slash (/), which is also variously known as a *solidus*, *virgule*, or just plain *slash*, when the deletion of a single character is to be marked. The *solidus* was a Roman coin and is ultimately the basis for English *soldier*, the idea being that a soldier is someone who fights for money, or, as we might say today, a *mercenary* (from the Latin *merces* ‘wages.’) The solidus as slash is historically a straightened-out *S*, the abbreviation for the English shilling (as in 2/3—two shillings thruppence), the step from one coin to another being relatively easy. How we get from shilling to slash in its various other uses—as proofreader’s strike-out mark, arithmetical sign of division, general separatrix, and so on—is rather more murky.

Comment: Is there a connection between its use here, and how it gained its use in the current form as meaning this/that? Maybe a good englishSE post.

Comment: @akozi: See the last sentence of the above quote. I am unable to add any more information.

Comment: Just to note that the archaic [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) is closer to a slash than the modern form.

Comment: As an arithmetical division sign it's easy to see how ½ becomes 1/2 on a typewriter, and I don't think one has to look for any connection with the use to mean "shillings". Of course 1/5½ to mean one-and-fivepence-ha'penny (one shilling, five and half pence) needs a proper fraction symbol, otherwise it has to be written 1s 5 1/2d.

Comment: Related: [Why is backslash called BACK slash when arguably it points forward?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/92390/45414)